# How to use <EmptyDataTemplate> in asp gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid as follows

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFgOrder" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Order ID</th>
                <th>Total Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">No records found</td>
            </tr>
       </thead>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order ID" DataField="OrderID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Price" DataField="TotalPrice" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

When the data source is not null the data is sown in `<table><tbody>` as expected

Whenever the data source is null the empty template is rendered. But the problem is an empty row is added in `<tbody>` tag as

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
                 <td>Order ID</td>
                 <td>Total Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">No records found</td>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
          <tr><td></td><tr>                  
   </tbody>  
</table>
```

How can eliminate this table row from tbody. I have attached a click listener to `<tbody>` `<tr>`
So unwanted care is required in javascript.

How can I get around this?
Is this the proper way of using a `<EmptyDataTemplate>`?

My Aim is to show as follows when datasource is empty

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to hide entire grid if the data source is null right?

Did you try hiding grid if the source is null?

Comment: No. I want to show the empty template when the source is null and to remove the empty row in tbody at that time. I was wondering why an empty row is added

Comment: do you need to show the header when the grid is empty?

Comment: Yes. That will be appealing to the user.I have seen like it in some sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the solution
Adding the line

```
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="hide" />
```

Saved my day. This causes the extra tbody tr to be hidden when data source is null.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a div inside the emptydatatemplate instead of thead and tr tags.

Comment: +1. This is right. A `div` should be used for `EmptyDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are adding that into a `thead`. Hence regular `tbody` is also being generated albeit empty.

Just specify the row:

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">No records found</td>
        </tr>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

You could also use `EmptyDataText`

```
<GridView ... EmptyDataText="[ No details available... ]" >
```

Comment: Now 2 rows are showing up. one with no records found and empty row
I would like to show the headers also when the datasource is null

Comment: @Robert_Junior: Use a `div` instead of a table row as @Dev suggested.